# Validação em vários input file com JS

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Galera eu tenho um código JS para validação dos anexos do formulário e estou tetando chamar a função uma única vez para todos os campos com a mesma `class=""` o problema é que ele funciona apenas com a primeira view o mesmo campo nas outras views não passa pela validação, segue os códigos.

**valida-anexo.js //função chamada na include header.php**

```
function verifica_extensao()
      {
      var arquivo = $(".input_anexo").val();

      var extensoes_permitidas = new Array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".pdf", ".php", ".js", ".swf", ".zip", ".rar", ".bmp", ".css", ".html", ".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".word", ".7zip");
      var erro = "";
      if ($.trim(arquivo)=="")
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
          var extensao = (arquivo.substring(arquivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
          var permitida = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < extensoes_permitidas.length; i++) 
          {
            console.log("if ("+extensoes_permitidas[i]+" == "+extensao+") ");
            if (extensoes_permitidas[i] == extensao) 
            {
              permitida = true;
              break;
            }
          }
      }

      if (!permitida)
      {
        var ext_perm = "";
        for (a in extensoes_permitidas)
        {
          ext_perm += ext_perm == "" ? extensoes_permitidas[a] : " , " + extensoes_permitidas[a];
        }

        alert("Somente permitido envio de imagens com as seguintes extensoes: "+ext_perm);
        return false;
      }

      return true;
      }
```

esse form está em duas views diferentes e funciona apenas na primeira.

**nova_pergunta.php //form para criar nova pergunta**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(current_url(), 'class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return verifica_extensao()"'); ?>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Área</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="i_area" class="input-large">
            <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecione uma Área</option>
            <?php 
                $query = $this->db->get('areas')->result_array();
                foreach ($query as $data) :
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['i_area']; ?>"><?php echo $data['nome']; ?></option>
            <?php 
                endforeach;
            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Título</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <?php echo form_input('titulo', set_value('titulo'), 'class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Digite um Título"'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Descrição</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <?php echo form_textarea('descricao', set_value('descricao'), 'class="input-xxlarge" rows="10" placeholder="Mensagem que será enviada e lida pelo técnico"'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Arquivo</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <?php echo form_upload(array('name' => 'anexo_msg', 'class' => 'input_anexo')); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
        <?php 
            echo validation_errors('<p class="text-error">', '</p>'); 
            if ($this->session->flashdata('msgok') != "")   echo '<p class="text-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('msgok').'</p>';
          if ($this->session->flashdata('msgerror') != "") echo $this->session->flashdata('msgerror');
        ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar ao Suporte</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`var arquivo = $(".input_anexo").val();` só está a apanhar o primeiro elemento que ele encontra; terá que fazer um loop que veja se os valores de cada elemento `input_anexo` são permitidos ou não; Segue um exemplo:

```
var arquivos = $('.input_anexo');
var extensoes_permitidas = new Array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".pdf", ".php", ".js", ".swf", ".zip", ".rar", ".bmp", ".css", ".html", ".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".word", ".7zip");
var arquivo = [],i,ext;
arquivos.each(function(ele) {
    arquivo.push($(ele).val());
});
i = arquivo.length;
for (i=0;i<=arquivo.length;i++) {
    ext = arquivo[i];
    var permitida = false;
      for (var a = 0; i < extensoes_permitidas.length; a++) {
        console.log("if ("+extensoes_permitidas[a]+" == "+ext+") ");
        if (extensoes_permitidas[a] == ext) {
          permitida = true;
          break;
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: fiz a alteração no código mais o resultado é o mesmo, agora nem a primeira view valida.

Comment: @Japa eu escrevi uma solução, terás que adaptar o código ao teu - embora eu tenha usado parte do teu código a lógica do mesmo mudou. Fica-nos mais facil ajudar-te se conseguires fazer um [JSFiddle](www.jsfiddle.net) e passares o link para o teu fiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/279fztoz/

Comment: @Japa arranja esse fiddle para não ter PHP, PHP não funciona no fiddle. Vai ao teu site, "view html source" e cola no fiddle o html que é preciso